# Displaying neutral search results on Google

Tags: google-search

If a users search results on Google get gradually personalised through individual use, how do I display or simulate a neutral user to compare past and previous listing positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really as it is not just the personalised results that are changed it is also your geographic location, the device you are searching from etc. There is no definitive "neutral search result" per se.

That said just go into private browsing (Control + Shift + N in Chrome) to be anonymous and therefore have non-personalised results.

Comment: This is simply wrong. Google has multiple indicators to find out if you are the same person in "private browsing" then in the normal mode. e.g. IP address, browser, operating system, screen width, available browser plugins, ... If you really would like to search "neutral" you would have to remove all those indicators :-)

Comment: Which part of this is wrong? The question was about "personalised results" not about whether Google can identify you as the same person or not.